# Hashtable и проблема с заменой символов в массиве

Tags: c#, replace

Делаю переводчик в ситуации когда ты пишешь огромный текст на русском, а он на английском.
Пример: "ghbdtn" - "привет"
Всё работает отлично, но если текст вводить с цифрами или символами то они не отображаются в выводе.
По нажатию кнопки происходит следующий код:

```
char[] translateChar = englishText.Text.ToCharArray();


Hashtable hashTbEngRus = new Hashtable
{

    // Здесь хранится ключ в виде английских букв и значение в русских.

};
ICollection key = hashTbEngRus.Keys;


for (int i = 0; i < translateChar.Length; i++)
{ 
    foreach (char lengthKey in key)
    {
        if (lengthKey == translateChar[i])
        {
            russianText.Text += englishText.Text.Replace(translateChar[i].ToString(), hashTbEngRus[lengthKey].ToString())[i];
            break;
        }
    }              
}
```

Я много вариантов проверил но никак не найду решение, проблема заключается в том, что цикл foreach проходится по всему ключу и если добавить
`else russianText.Text += translateChar[i];`
Оно будет выводить каждый элемент массива повторно пока не найдёт равный из-за чего в выводе получается полная фигня. Может не стоило работать тут с Hashtable или есть всё таки решение кроме того как добавить все символы, цифры и русские буквы.
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: К WPF этот вопрос не имеет прямого отношения, убрал метку с вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте обобщённые коллекции, и зря весь код не показали.

```
string text = englishText.Text;

Dictionary<char, char> map = new()
{
    ['A'] = 'Ф',
    // ...
};

StringBuilder sb = new(text.Length);
foreach (char c in text)
{ 
    sb.Append(map.TryGetValue(c, out char x) ? x : c);
}
russianText.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Вот и всего делов.

`Dictionary` это то же самое что `Hashtable` только новее, быстрее и удобнее.

`StringBuilder` здесь используется для производительности и экономии памяти, он намного эффективнее, чем конкатенация строк. Используйте его если надо много клеить и резать строк, например как здесь. `text.Length` в конструкторе SB означает начальную ёмкость внутреннего хранилища билдера, указывать необязательно, но полезно, если заранее знаете, какой длины будет результат.

С тернарным оператором `?:` надеюсь не возникнет сложности разобраться.

Если совсем сложно, то вот тело цикла попроще, делает то же самое.

```
if (map.ContainsKey(c))
    sb.Append(map[c]);
else
    sb.Append(c);
```

Разница только в том, что `TryGetValue` за один проход проверяет, есть ли ключ и сразу достаёт значение, если есть, а здесь сначала ищем, чтобы проверить, затем второй раз по индексатору, чтобы забрать символ. То есть в 2 раза медленнее этот код, но для коротких строк без разницы.

Comment: Огромное спасибо, думал про словарь, но кто-то говорил что от  хэш-таблицы разницы нет вообще.
Насчёт всего кода. Кроме кнопки копировать, вставить и очистить ничего нет